# Adding multiple lines to a Google line chart

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

So, I did a page with lots of data from Pingdom.
The page itself contains several Google Line Charts and those work perfectly when I'm only showing info for a single checkid.

But when I'm trying to add multiple lines (to be able to show several checkids in one chart) it just doesn't work as it should.

The lines are being drawn, however they are not drawn on top of each other! :(

Below is my code for trying to add several lines to the line chart.
Please note that the php-file that fetch information from the database, does this through a $_GET variable (you'll see later on in the JavaScript code why as I'm trying to join all of the datasets into one dataset)

NOTE:
Currently, parts of the code below needs a lot of extra work, so don't bother pointing out security flaws. I just need the graphs to work before I go ahead and fix the security stuff.

PHP:

```
<?php
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Oslo'));

$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","PingdomStats");
$checkId = $_GET['checkId'];


// first we need to list out all the internal checks
$sql = "SELECT CheckId, CheckName, Category FROM Checks WHERE CheckId=$checkId ";
$checkList = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$checkListCopy = $checkList;
$sqlResponseTimes = "";

$rows = array();
$table = array();

$table['cols'] = 
array
(
  array('label' => 'Check name', 'type' => 'string'),
  array('label' => 'Response time', 'type' => 'number')
);


if(mysqli_num_rows($checkList) > 0)
{

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($checkList))
  {
    $sqlResponseTimes = "   SELECT 
                            FROM_UNIXTIME(Resp.checkTime, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') AS CheckTime,
                            Resp.ResponseTime AS '$row[1]'
                            FROM ResponseTimes AS Resp
                            WHERE
                            Resp.Checkid = $row[0]
                            ORDER BY Resp.Id DESC LIMIT 10 ";




    //do a new query based on the sql query we just created.

    $responseTimeList = mysqli_query($con,$sqlResponseTimes);

    while($rowInner = mysqli_fetch_array($responseTimeList,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $temp = array();
        $temp[] = array('v' => (string)$row[1]." ".$rowInner['CheckTime']); 
        $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $rowInner[$row[1]]); 

        $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;

echo json_encode($table);
}
```

And here is the JS code:

```
var jsonData0 = 
$.ajax(
{
   url: "important_test.php?checkId=1575894",
   dataType:"json",
   async: false
}).responseText;

var data0 = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData0);

var jsonData1 = 
$.ajax(
{
   url: "important_test.php?checkId=1653903",
   dataType:"json",
   async: false
}).responseText;

var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData1);

var jsonData2 = 
$.ajax(
{
   url: "important_test.php?checkId=1575824",
   dataType:"json",
   async: false
}).responseText;

var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData2);

var jsonData3 = 
$.ajax(
{
   url: "important_test.php?checkId=1579531",
   dataType:"json",
   async: false
}).responseText;

var data3 = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData3);

var jsonData4 = 
$.ajax(
{
   url: "important_test.php?checkId=1645709",
   dataType:"json",
   async: false
}).responseText;

var data4 = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData4);

var options = 
{
   curveType: 'function',
   is3D: true,
   width: document.getElementById('internalLineGraph').clientWidth,
   height: 400,

};

var join_data0_Data1 = new google.visualization.data.join(data0,data1,'full',[[0,0]],[1],[1]);

var join_data2_Data3 = new google.visualization.data.join(data2,data3,'full',[[0,0]],[1],[1]);

var data0_to_data3 = new google.visualization.data.join(data0_Data1,data2_Data3,'full',[[0,0]],[1,2],[1,2]);

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('internalLineGraph'));

chart.draw(data0_to_data3, options);
```

See attached picture:
[Graph showing info from internal Pingdom database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmFQ3.png)

Comment: Never mind my question, I solved it myself during my exercise session today..! :]

I forgot to add a common ID in the json table ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add a common ID to be able to join the JSON tables.
Now it work as it should!